# Divisions and remainders

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This probelm is taken from the "Introduction to Number Theory" by Hua Luogeng.

Let $\left[x\right]$ denotes the integer part of a number.  Thus $\left[3.14\right] = 3$.

Let x be any number, and n is an integer. Can you prove that

$$
\left[x\right] + \left[x + \frac{1}{n}\right] + \left[x + \frac{2}{n}\right] + ... + \left[x + \frac{n-1}{n}\right] = \left[nx\right]
$$

My approach is: put x = [x] + e, where $ 0 \le e < 1$.  The left hand side is reduced to:

$$
n\left[x\right] + \sum_{r=1}^{n-1}\left[e+\frac{r}{n}\right]
$$

Whereas the right hand side is equivalent to

$$
\left[ne\right]
$$

But I have difficulties proceeding further.

Comment: The right hand side is $n[x]+[ne] $ so you basically only have to prove the equation for $0\leq x<1$ consider what happens when $x\in[0,1/n) $ what about $[1/n,2/n)$?

Comment: Let $k$ be the largest integer such that $\frac{k}{n}\le e\lt\frac{k+1}{n}$ and show that both sides equal $n[x]+k$.